# For loop after import doesn't work in Python one-liner

Tags: python, import, terminal, syntax-error

If I use `import` and a `for` follows afterwards I get an `invalid syntax` error. I have no idea why this happens.

```
> python3 -c 'import os; for a in range(1,5): print(a)'
  File "<string>", line 1
    import os; for a in range(1,5): print(a)
                 ^
```

Removing the `import` works fine:

```
> python3 -c 'for a in range(1,5): print(a)'
1
2
3
4
```

or totally removing the `for` loop:

```
> python3 -c 'import os; print(10)'
10
```

So what's going on??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an error because it's not in the Python grammar.

If you check out the [syntax specification for compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-compound_stmt), you'll see that a statement list (i.e. what you're making with the semicolon) is defined as:

`stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]`

and the `for` construct is not a `simple_stmt`, but instead is a `compound_stmt`.

The `print(10)`, however, is a `simple_stmt` and, as such, is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Well in 2022 with python3 you can do this:

```
python3 -c 'import os; [print(a) for a in range(1,5)]'
```

Answer (score 1):

As you see Python does not allow you to put a block opening statement (like `for`) into a line with an other statement.
In general you should not use the `;` inside a script in some situations it (like the command execution of python code with `-c`) it is the only solution, but inside a script just use a line break.

For details about coding style standards in  Python you can read the PEP 8: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

Convert the single line code to multiple line form and replace the line breaks with "\n".  Then pass that as a string to the exec function:

```
python3 -c "exec('import os\nfor a in range(1,5):\n print(a)')"
```

Not elegant, but it accomplishes the task without the need for a script file.

Answer (score 0):

just as another workaround
in bash:

python3 -c "import datetime;import sys"$'\n'"for i in range(10):    print(i)"

Answer (score 0):

It's true that Python syntax doesn't support the for loop as you've written it, but at least you can still use a comprehension to achieve what you've illustrated in your post:

```py
import os; print([a for a in range(1,5)])
```

Or more accurately:

```py
import os; print("\n".join([str(a) for a in range(1,5)]))
```