# Python SyntaxError in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, syntax-error

I am trying to extract some particular data from the JSON so i wrote the following code

```
echo "$Group_ID" | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); for o in obj: if o[name] == "Admin_UserGroup": print o["id"]';
```

But its throwing error

Can someone please help and tell me what wrong with the code?

```
   File "<string>", line 1
     import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); for o in obj: if o["name"] == "Admin_UserGroup": print o["id"]
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is the version details

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

**EDIT 1 : Attaching the image**

[image]

Comment: Do you use Python 2?

Comment: Did you try executing it as a normal script (not on a single line)?

Comment: @MartinThoma I updated version information and yes i am trying it in single line .

Comment: @U9-Forward In this example https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp they wrote same.

Comment: @AdamSmith Sorry, i was wrong, from the one line of whole code is confusing me

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I am suggesting to use multiple lines. I don't see a point in having it in a single line...

Comment: I've attempted to edit your post to match the picture you posted below. You improperly copied the code *and* didn't give us all the info in the error traceback. The solution is to write a python script, not to one-line it.

Comment: As noted in the linked dupe and [also this closely-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26778181/for-loop-after-import-doesnt-work-in-python-one-liner), what your trying to do cannot be done in a one-liner. As many many many have told you already: write a script.

Comment: @KGS Your multiple line code worked but i dont want to print none.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi your own code will work when you write it as a script. The only problem here is attempting to separate simple and compound statements with a semicolon, which is not accepted in the Python grammar.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks can you please tell how to avoid the print none?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Use your own code! It doesn't print `None`. I don't know why KGSH was trying to get you to use that ternary idiom `if pred then a else b`. It's not useful for the task at hand.

Comment: @AdamSmith Ok i will see the feasibility for my requirement to write python code in a file.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I have found a way to do it in one line - Please read my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should also post the `Error` - 'Syntax Error'

Also, this will be helpful: [One-line list comprehension: if-else variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321138/one-line-list-comprehension-if-else-variants)

Therefore, this python code should work for you:

```
import json ,sys;
obj = json.load(sys.stdin);
print ('\n'.join([str(o["id"]) if o[name] == "Admin_UserGroup" else "" for i in obj]).replace('\n\n','\n').strip('\n'))
```

Shrink it into a one liner:

```
echo "$Group_ID" | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print ('\n'.join([str(o['id']) if o[name] == 'Admin_UserGroup' else '' for i in obj]).replace('\n\n','\n').strip('\n'))";
```

**EDIT:**
After 10 minutes of bug fixing, this works!
Let's print the even numbers in 1 - 10:

```
print('\n'.join([str(i) if i % 2 == 0 else '' for i in range(1, 11)]).replace('\n\n','\n').strip('\n'))
```

Which outputs as expected

**EDIT 2:**
you cannot use single quotes in your python command

**Edit 3: Working command**

```
[root@mdfdevha1 ~]# echo "$Group_ID" | python -c "import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin);print ('\n'.join([str(i['id']) if i['name'] == 'Admin_UserGroup' else '' for i in obj]).replace('\n\n','\n').strip('\n' ))";
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is different.

Comment: It's different because it works

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ If whole command in one line its a issue in Python ,as i dont know python .

Comment: Since the code is throwing an error on the `for` loop (even with your code) I beg to differ.

Comment: There's no reason to use the `if pred then a else b` idiom here. Note that `print number` is also equal `None` (with a side effect). Just `if number % 2: print number` is fine -- it just doesn't work in this context (after an import statement and a semicolon in a one-line expression)

Comment: Yep - I just tried to make it work in 1 line

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ right, I understand, but if you'd tested it you'd have realized it still doesn't work....

Comment: All problems fixed

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ For your online command giving  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined`

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I can't seem to reproduce your error

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ one issue is object name will be `i` in place of `o` second after making this change its saying `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'name' is not defined` then i added `""` in name that also not worked But after adding single quotes its worked.

Comment: Double quotes don't work because your `python -c ..` is bracketed with double quotes, and if you use it in your python script it will 'crash'

Comment: @KGSHbteamMineTeamBeastO_ I updated your answer with working command Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The key of a JSON should be given within quotes.

Try this:

```
echo "$Group_ID" | python -c 'import json,sys;obj=json.load(sys.stdin); for o in obj: if o["name"] == "Admin_UserGroup": print o["id"]'
```

Thanks

Comment: Same exception from above command as well.

Comment: Try removing the semicolons in the python script. That could help.

Comment: @SmashGuy that's not valid Python anymore, then. You're grasping at straws -- test something.

Comment: Please test your code before posting...

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the new idiom. But i have never seen semicolon before as i have not worked in Python 2x.

Comment: It still gives Invalid Syntax

Comment: @SmashGuy It's not Python2 introducing the semicolon -- it's a way to separate what *should* be newline-separated statements in one-line code. It's silly, and the **real** solution is to write a script.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Can you provide the JSON object?

Comment: @SmashGuy Added JSON object as well